# Realize SaveOptions behavior in XPages

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I like to create an XPage which have the same usability in the save behavior like a notes document, special I like to realize the `SaveOptions` behavior 'When the User change something, the system remember him to save and if the user save, the system to not remember him'.

I found out a 50% solution, over the data->enableModifiedFlag property the system recognized if the user change something in the document and if so post the string that is stored in the data->ModifiedMessage property.

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" enableModifiedFlag="true">
     <xp:this.modifiedMessage><![CDATA["please Save"]]></xp:this.modifiedMessage>
</xp:view>
```

But if I save the Document in the datasource and like to leave the site, the post still occur.

How could I realize that when the XPages-Doc is different to the dataSourceDoc the post occur, and if the XPages-Doc is equal to the dataSourceDoc, the Post not occur?

Comment: This seems to be problem how to reset modified flag after document is saved. Maybe reload would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

enableModifiedFlag allows you to refine the functionality.

Custom Controls also have an enableModifiedFlag, which should allow you to give a message only if something in that custom control has changed.

Individual input controls have a disableModifiedFlag that can be set to true, to ensure that particular control is ignored when identifying if the page has been modified or not.

A Button of type "Cancel" will ignore enableModified and just move on.

You can also programmatically set or clear the modified flag in CSJS (XSP._setDirty(false,""). There is also a view.setEnableModifiedFlag(boolean) method that can be used to change the enableModifiedFlag property on an XPage from SSJS.

Panels don't have an enableModifiedFlag or disableModifiedFlag property, but with the options I mentioned it should give you the control you need.

Comment: The CSJS method works fine, the ssjs method not work in my onclick event. <xp:button value="Speichern" id="button2">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="norefresh" immediate="false" save="true">
<xp:this.action>      <xp:actionGroup><xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument><xp:confirm message="Gespeichert"></xp:confirm><xp:executeScript script="#{javascript:view.setEnableModifiedFlag(false)}"> </xp:executeScript></xp:actionGroup></xp:this.action></xp:eventHandler></xp:button>

Comment: I suspect that view.setEnableModifiedFlag(false) sets a property on the xp:view tag that, when that area is written to the browser, adds an HTML attribute onto the body tag (that corresponds to xp:view of the XPage). Because you're doing refreshMode="norefresh", the HTML for the body tag won't get updated. You'll probably need to set refreshMode to full for it to work.